# Overlapping of elements after multipage table in tcpdf

Tags: php, tcpdf

After echoing  product list (usually multipage)the below content get overlapping to the first page.I have been try to solve this problem form so many no luck so for .I have seen some topic on stack over flow but doesn't work for me. Below is full working code showing above problem. How could I solve this.Full solution is greatly appreciated.

```
    $InvAllPrct = '';
$InvAllPrct .= '<div><br>
<table border="0"  cellpadding="3" style="width:100%">
<tbody>
<tr style="font-weight: bold;">
<th style="width: 6%;">Product</th>
<th style="width: 6%;">Price</th>
<th style="width: 4%;">QTY</th>
<th style="width: 7%;">Total</th>
</tr><hr>';
//----------------------get prct information-----------------------------------------------

for($i=0;$i<100;$i++){
    $InvAllPrct .= '<tr>
    <td style="text-align: right;">Some text</td>
    <td style="text-align: right;">100</td>
    <td style="text-align: right;">1</td>
    <td style="text-align: right;">100</td>
    </tr>';
}

$InvAllPrct .= '</tbody>
</table>
<hr style="font-weight:bold;">
</div>';

$Cname = '';
$Cname .= '<div style="float:right;">';
$Cname .= '<span style="font-weight: 600;font-style: oblique;font-size: 12px;">Some company name</span><br>';
$Cname .= '<span> some text</span><br>';
$Cname .= '</div>';


//---------------------------tax n total---------------------------------------------   
$GrandTotalData = '';
$GrandTotalData .= '
<span>Sub Total: 100</span><br>';
$GrandTotalData .= '<span> tax1 : 10%</span><br>';
$GrandTotalData .= '<span> tax2 : 10%</span><br>';
$GrandTotalData .= '<span>Total : 200</span><br>';
$GrandTotalData .= '<span style=" font-weight: bold;">Grand Total : 200<hr></<span>';
// Include the main TCPDF library (search for installation path).
require('tcpdf1/tcpdf.php');

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));


// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 10);
$pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);
// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->MultiCell(00, 00, "Some text", 0, 'C', 0, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, true, 40, 'T');

$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 7);
// create some HTML content
$y = $pdf->getY();

$pdf->writeHTMLCell('', '', '46', $y,"Some Name", 0, 0, 0, true, 'J', false);
$y = $pdf->getLastH()+$y;

$pdf->writeHTMLCell('', '', 10, $y, $InvAllPrct, 0, 0, 0, true, 'J', true);
$y = $pdf->getLastH()+$y;
// // ******Problem Starts here overlapping on above content on first page***************
$pdf->writeHTMLCell('38', '', 160, $y, $GrandTotalData, 0, 0, 0, true, 'J', true);
$html = '<div style="text-align:centre;"> Some Text......................................</div>';
$y = $pdf->getLastH()+$y;

$pdf->writeHTMLCell('', '', '', $y, $html, 0, 0, 0, true, 'J', true);
$y = $pdf->getLastH()+$y;

$html = '<div style="text-align: justify;margin: 0px 225px 17px 5px;">Some long text here.................</div><br>
<div style="text-align: justify;margin: 0px 225px 36px 5px;">Some long text here.....................</div>
';

$pdf->writeHTMLCell('144', '', '', $y, $html, 0, 0, 0, true, 'J', true);

$pdf->lastPage();

$pdf->Output('example_006.pdf', 'I');
```

php tcpdf

Comment: Hard to guess if you are facing the same issue, but it looks related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35318280/tcpdf-sometime-add-new-page-then-next-page-content-overflows/39986334#39986334

Comment: Try the above code but this doent work for me . $GrandTotalData is printed on first page instead of last page

Comment: Try to create a [minimal reproducer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You have got a lot of useless things in your code. Minimal reproducer helps you and people willing to help you to understand the problem and solve it.

Comment: I updated the code as minimal as possible and is fully working code showing the problem I have.